# Rad Grid Not Selecting Row On Row Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Rad Grid that I bind a data source to in the Page Load. I am trying to then capture the row that is selected when the user clicks a row. I have successfully done this with a Rad Grid that has a data source set in the markup. Is it possible to do this with a grid with a dynamically set data source.

**Markup**

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgTable" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rgTable_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
        <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**C#**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        ConnString = Connections.Search(0, 999999, null, null, null, id, null, null, null, null, null)[0].Connection_String;

        StoreTableAndViewNames();//This method sets arrTables with ArrayList
        rgTable.DataSource = arrTables;
        rgTable.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rgTable_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (rgTable.SelectedItems.Count > 0)//This test is failing
            {
                GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)rgTable.SelectedItems[0];
                string table = item.Cells[0].ToString();

                StoreColumnNames(table);
                rgColumn.DataSource = arrColumns;
                rgColumn.DataBind();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorlbl.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, Data is bind to rgTable on ever page load.

As the result, when a row is selected at client side, data is bind to`rgTable` again before `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is fired.

### The quick fixes is not to bind rgTable on post back.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ....
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    rgTable.DataSource = arrTables;
    rgTable.DataBind();
  }
}
```

### However, preferred method is to use NeedDataSource event

If you bind data in `NeedDataSource` event, RadGrid knows when & where to look for data if it is needed.

```
protected void rgTable_OnNeedDataSource(object sender, 
   GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   rgTable.DataSource = arrTables;   
}
```

Comment: I use NeedDataSource event and I have the same: I can not select any row.
I create arrTables instance in event method according to the telerik documenattion (the example in it).